# For loop syntax, iterating over an array

Tags: solidity

In this example:

> ```
>   uint i;
>     uint j;
>     for(i=0;i<_baseBytes.length;i++) {
>         _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
>     }
> ```
>
> in the `_newValue` variable why is `j++` been used. Surely `_newValue[i]` would suffice?

Comment: Maybe it is used as an example of how not to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. It's exactly the same output.